# Lucene using FSDirectory

Tags: java, lucene

I wrote a simple java program to create a lucene index, but I get an error with the syntax.

My code:

```
static final String INDEX_DIRECTORY = "/home/yuqing/Desktop/index";
Directory index = FSDirectory.open(new File(INDEX_DIRECTORY));
```

I get the following error,

```
open (java.nio.file.path) in FSDirectory cannot be applied to java.io.file
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`FSDirectory.open`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory.html#open(java.nio.file.Path)) call takes a `Path` argument, not a `File` (as of Lucene version 5.0).  You can check out the [Java tutorial on the Path Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathClass.html) for information on how it works.

So, your code should look like:

```
static final String INDEX_DIRECTORY = "/home/yuqing/Desktop/index";
Directory index = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_DIRECTORY));
```

Comment: should handle IO Exception; 

import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

Directory index;
public methodName throws IOException {
       try {
         static final String INDEX_DIRECTORY = "/home/yuqing/Desktop/index";
      index = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_DIRECTORY));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Answer (score 2):

You should use .toPath() for the path to files.

```
File f=new File(INDEX_DIRECTORY);
Directory index = FSDirectory.open(f.toPath());
```